# Printing whole table by using dbmail sp

Tags: sql-server, html-table, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to print the table result in mail body, but when it was executed only one row of the result is fetching and printing in mail.

the output should be printed in tabular form, whole table result should be  in mail body.

```html
SELECT 
 @str1 =
 COALESCE(@str1 + ' ', '') +
 --'<tr><td align="right">' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CURRENT_DTM, 109) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), MIN_START_DTM, 109), 0) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), MAX_END_DTM, 109), 0) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="left">' + SERVER + '</td>' +
 --'<td align="left">' +  + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, TXN_CNT_LAST_HR), 1), '.00', '')) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(MONEY, AVG_RESPONSE_LAST_HR), 1), '.00', '')) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), TXN_Less_2_SEC), 0) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), TXN_GRTR_5_SEC), 0) + '</td>' +
 '<td align="right">' + ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), TXN_GR_2sec_LS_5_SEC), 0) + '</td></tr> '
FROM ##Report
ORDER BY  SERVER,TXN_CNT_LAST_HR
  
SET @str1 = ISNULL(@str1, '<tr>No records to show</tr>')

SET @rpt =
N'<table>' +
N'<table border = 1>' +
N'<tr><th colspan=5>Txn = Transaction, Resp = Response Time</th><th colspan=3>Txn count with Resp more than</th></tr>' +
N'<th>Min Timestamp</th>' +
N'<th>Max Timestamp</th>' +
N'<th>Server</th>' +
N'<th >Txn Count</th>' +
N'<th>Avg Resp (seconds)</th>' +
N'<th>2 sec</th>' +
N'<th>5 sec</th>' +
N'<th>2 to 5 sec</th></tr>' +
@str1 + 
N'</table>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='MainMail',
        @recipients = 'mspatewar007@gmail.com'
        ,@subject = 'Report'
        ,@body = @rpt
        ,@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: Check out https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/sqlclr-practice-creating-better-way-sending-email-sql-server/

Comment: Hi @Matthew Evans I have added the code in post. Please check.

Comment: Take a look to [CURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Tried with cursor also but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are setting a variable's value to the concatenation based on the number of records in  ##report. How do you expect multiple values?

Comment: So @Ross Bush , could you please help me in that.

Comment: Does each record in ##report translate to an html "section" and how many sections do you expect to display in the email?

Comment: @Ross Bush , yes, it's displaying all the sections but not displaying all the rows from ##report.

Comment: Have you tried embedding a CTRL/LF into your string?

Comment: @Ross Bush, Already added my code in the post, could you please check that. Any modifications in code are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to append a CTRL/LF into your string. Test this and see if it works.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(25))
INSERT @T VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')

DECLARE @HTML1 NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''-- <-- Set this to empty string to avoid concatenation a string with a null equals null
DECLARE @HTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX)  = ''-- <-- Set this to empty string to avoid concatenation a string with a null equals null

SELECT 
    @HTML1 = @HTML1 + ISNULL(ID+ ':)' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),''), -- <-- Embed a CTRL/LF
    @HTML2 = @HTML2 + ISNULL(ID+ ':)','')
FROM @T

PRINT @HTML1
PRINT @HTML2
```